# Ignoring newline characters with fscanf()

Tags: c, file-io

I'm reading a multi-line file with the `fscanf()` function.  I'd like to ignore the newline characters, but not other whitespace characters that might be in the file.  How can I best do this?

Comment: You need to pick a language, first. C or C++. They are different languages.

Comment: What format are you trying to parse?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm using C, but isn't this a legacy function in c++ as well?  Anyone familiar with c++ should be familiar with fscanf()

Comment: @chqrlie I'm working with regular text files.  All of them contain whitespace characters that are essential, which is why I don't want to remove all whitespace; only newlines

Comment: Why don't you use `fgets()`?

Comment: If you're "using C", then a C++ answer is not something that will be useful to you; yet by tagging your question with C++, you will be wasting the time of anyone who would care to provide a C++-only answer.

Comment: @DavidBowling I'd like to parse individual characters.  As I understand it, `fgets()` will read the entire line as a string

Comment: That is true. You could parse the string after reading it in from the file. The whitespace characters will still be there, as will the trailing newline (which you can remove if you want).

Comment: Or why not use `getc()` if you want to take only one character at a time?

Comment: That is a viable option, I'll probably do that.  Not sure if it really answers the original question since it's an alternative, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this does what you ask:

```
char ch[2];
while (fscanf(fp, "%1[^\n]%*[\n]", ch) == 1)
    putchar(ch[0]);
```

The first format specifier reads up to one character that is not a newline and stores it in the string `ch`, and the second specifier reads newlines but suppresses assignment. The result of this loop is to print all of the characters in the file, skipping over newlines, until `EOF`.

@AnT has pointed out in the comments that this method will fail for a text file the starts with a newline character, and has suggested the fix: a call to `fscanf()` before the loop that reads newlines while suppressing assignment. The improved code is:

```
char ch[2];
fscanf(fp, "%*[\n]");
while (fscanf(fp, "%1[^\n]%*[\n]", ch) == 1)
    putchar(ch[0]);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that this `fscanf` will immediately fail and exit the cycle if the input begins with a newline.

Comment: But couldn't you just do `scanf("%*[\n]");` before the cycle?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in ignoring the newline characters, using `getc()` is simpler and more efficient than using `fscanf()`:

```
void copy_ignoring_newline(FILE *fin, FILE *fout) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getc(fin)) != EOF) {
        if (c != '\n')
            putc(c, fout);
    }
}
```

You can adapt this for any processing you want to perform on the file contents.

`fscanf()` is a very clunky interface for parsing files, it treats spaces, newlines and other whitespace characters the same, except for the `%c` and the `%[` conversion specifiers.  An alternative approach with `getc()`, `fgets()`, or `fread()` seems better suited to you needs.